# JavaScript alert title header

Tags: javascript

I want to change JavaScript alert title header from displaying Internet Explorer to another name. is a way to do it?

I found these site in the net:

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/148721-change-title-bar-javascript-alert-box

[How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Which say that there is no solution. Is it true there are no other way?

Comment: You can always create your custom alert box.

Comment: dear Secko..custom alert box? what's that? can i get more info? i do know how to get window popup by using window.open, but that window doesnot look like alert box...thx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I confirm that. There is no way.

[There seems to be a solution for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title/1905335#1905335) using client-side VBScript, but I wouldn't really recommend that path.

Actually, I wouldn't recommend using the `alert()` function altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, popping up an alert dialog [and blocking input to the main browser window] is sort of annoying.

It's more appealing to the user if you just stick a div in the middle of the screen.  Plus, it's more style-able...

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the title of alert boxes in javascript. Its browser Property. But you can use Jquery custom Dialogue Boxes instead.