# Change Title of Javascript Alert

Tags: javascript

How can i change the title of javascript alert popup ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[You can't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert), this is determined by the browser, for the user's safety and security.  For example you can't make it say "Virus detected" with a message of "Would you like to quarantine it now?"...at least not as an `alert()`.

[There are plenty of JavaScript Modal Dialogs out there though](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+modal+dialog), that are *far* more customizable than `alert()`.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, you can't do that either using `alert()`or `confirm()`.

You can, however, create an external HTML document containing your error message and an `OK` button, set its `<title>` element to whatever you want, then display it in a modal dialog box using [showModalDialog()](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-showmodaldialog.shtml).

Answer (score 5):

Simple: you can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The alert is a simple popup where you only can affect the content text.

If you want to change anything else, you have to use a different way of creating a popup.

Answer (score 2):

you cant do this. Use a custom popup. Something like with the help of jQuery UI or jQuery BOXY.

for jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

for jQuery BOXY http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, sorry.
If really needed, you could use a jQuery plugin to have a custom alert.