# How to convert this javascript code into jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code like this:

```
function share22() {
    if(!isOneChecked('choice')) {
        alert('Please select the file..');
        return false;
        }
       document.getElementById('share_popup').style.display="block";
       }
```

I want to convert this dialog into simple jquery so that I can edit the title.

Comment: What does `isOneChecked('choice')` do ?

Comment: _"...to convert this dialog..."_ - What dialog would that be?

Comment: You can not edit the title : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   function share22() {
      if(!isOneChecked('choice')) {
       alert('Please select the file..');
       return false;
      }
      $("#share_popup").css("display", "block");
   }
```

Comment: Working but how can I edit the title.

Comment: visit question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172022/change-title-of-javascript-alert

Answer (score 1):

Considering `if(!isOneChecked('choice')) {` is checking for check box is checked or not

```
  function share22() {
     if ($(".choice").is(":not(:checked)")){
       alert('Please select the file..');
       return false;
     }
     $('#share_popup').show();
   }
```

Comment: OP doesn't say (of course), but I'll bet `isOneChecked()` tests that at least one of several is checked. Wouldn't `$(".choice").is(":not(:checked)")` return `true` if one of `.choice` is unchecked even if another _is_ checked?

Comment: @nnnnnn : Yeah...I edited the code, based on the assumption that "tests that at least one of several is checked."

Comment: Yes the assumption is correct.

Comment: Getting this error though: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @user1881957 : Edited the code I missed a `{`

Comment: How to edit the title to say anything instead of URL says

Comment: Where is the title in your question ?

Comment: I mean the title in alert box. The default is "URL says", I want to change it to 'Error'.

Comment: You can not change title for default browser alert. You need use custom alert boxes, you need write the code for that.

Comment: @user1881957 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title

Comment: @user1881957 : http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 0):

```
function share22() {
    if(!isOneChecked('choice')) {
        alert('Please select the file..');
        return false;
        }
       $('#share_popup').css("display","block");
       }
```

Comment: Satpal Singh already answered for this.

Comment: Working but How can I edit the title to say 'Anything' instead of URL says.