# How to remove site url from top of javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, php

I am using simple alert function of JavaScript that shows site URL when it executes.

How can I remove site url from top of javascript alert?

Is there any way to customize javascript alert?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172022/change-title-of-javascript-alert

Comment: What have you tried already? "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. __Include attempted solutions__, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove that. That's the default behaviour of a JavaScript Alert. The title attribute of a alert box cannot be modified.

You can make use of [**`JQuery`**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) Alert Dialog box to change the title as per your needs.