# MessageBox with meaningful title

Tags: xpages

When deleting documents in my application, I display a messagebox to confirm the deletion. However, the messagebox shows the correct message, but it also shows the server url instead of a meaningful messagebox title.

How can I modify the messagebox title to show something like "Document deletion" instead of the servername ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172022/change-title-of-javascript-alert

Comment: This is a browser specific issue. Use a modal dialog instead.

Comment: Does it matter? Speed of light has been broken by users who move the mouse to click on a button without reading the dialog ;-) - Sven put your comment in an answer so Eknori can accept it