# How can I change the title message of an alert box in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I change the title message of an alert box in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can not be done using javascript. But this can be done using jQuery. May be this url can help u.

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done. The title is browser dependent and you have no control over it. On the other hand you could implement your own alert box using divs and customize it as you like. Here's an example using the [jquery dialog plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is outside of your control and can not be changed

Answer (score 1):

This earlier question has some good suggestions in the answers : [how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)