# How to show alert box javascript on iphone UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, alert

its in iphone-UIWebView;

i have a html. also it contains tags like this

`<a href="javascript:alert('Clicked !')">sample</a>`

it works good, but there is written "documents" on the top of alert box, how can i remove? or change it?
or any idea about this stuation ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Comment: i solved the problem like this;
`<a href='zzz___1-doSomething'>`
`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    
    if ([[[[[[[request URL] absoluteString] lastPathComponent] componentsSeparatedByString:@"zzz___"] lastObject] substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"1-"])`