# Javascript Alert - Removing "The page at ??? Says"

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget, embed, alert

I have a form and I am using Javascript to validate the form so if you leave a field blank it will alert "Please fill in your Name".

If I go to the link directly, it works perfectly.  But this is kind of like a Widget so I am using an iFrame to embed it into other sites.  When I embed it, and click Submit with an empty field it says: **The page at http://www.example.com says:  Please fill in your name**

Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: It's a security measure, to prevent a malicious iframe from tricking you into thinking that the parent page is requesting private information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, there isn't. It is an anti-phishing feature.

If you want a dialog without it, then you have to fake it using HTML elements in your page.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking to use the native alert/confirm, it's not that hard to get past the anti-phishing implementation.  This is because the iframe can edit the parent and access it's scope.

Try this:

```
parent._alert = new parent.Function("alert(arguments[0]);");
parent._alert('Test!');
```

The reason this works is because **new Function('')** does not create a closure and instead uses the scope of where Function is defined (via parent.Function).

Comment: This did not work in my Chrome browser.  The "page at" text still appeared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some custom alert plugin. For example http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-dialog/