# When does the text "The page at ... says:" appear in a confirm popup?

Tags: javascript

As I understood, it is not possible to remove the *"The page at ... says"* line of text from the JavaScript standard confirm function. But, when exactly does it get generated? Sometimes the browser doesn't generate it, sometimes it does. What does it depend on?

Comment: see this similar link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996785/javascript-alert-removing-the-page-at-says

Comment: yeah, I saw it... I know that it is not possible to remove it, but sometimes browser doesnt generate it... and I wanted to know when it does and when it doesnt generate this line of text...

Comment: it does so when the code requests it to do so

Comment: "Sometimes the browser doesn't generate it" — Since browsers introduced that anti-phishing measure, I've never seen one generated which didn't include that notice.

Comment: from example, if I open this confirm test function in firefox , this line of text doesnt apper , but in chrome it does - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm

Comment: Sooooo… a difference between Firefox and Chrome...!?

Comment: but even in firefox sometimes it gets generated and sometimes not...

Comment: @Alex: From the question linked by yash you can see that one of the reasons to generate the text is when the alert comes from an iframe, i.e. a different page than the one whose uri you see in your address bar. There might be other reasons. Some browsers just add it by default.