# How do I remove "This page says: " from window.prompt()

Tags: javascript

```js
window.prompt("What's you're name?")
```

I just realized that the window.prompt() function inserts "This page says". I looked up how how to remove it but I only found how to remove it from alerts.

Comment: simple: you can't - can you show how you remove it from alerts? I didn't think that was possible either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Alert - Removing "The page at ??? Says"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996785/javascript-alert-removing-the-page-at-says)

Comment: basically this page says etc.etc. is a proxy server setting virus . you can not remove it . but instead of that you can use  a modal box to show as your wish .

Comment: @AzharKhan I was looking for the same thing but for window.prompt not alert

Comment: @ElioWhoCodes What makes you think that `alert` and `prompt` are different in this regard?