# Alert Messages in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('This is what an alert message looks like.');
</script>

function showAlert() {
    var country = "Fiji";
    var city = "Suva";
    alert('The city of ' + city + ' is located in ' + country + '.');
}

<input type="button" value="Click Here" onClick="showAlert();">
```

the result is:

> The city suva is located in Fiji.

K fine My doubt is: AlerBox contains "The page at localhost:1234 says".Here I want to define user-defined statement.How is it possible in javascript.

Help, please!

Comment: This has been discussed already. Please try searching before posting questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title

Comment: It not is possible, but you can use a custom alert, using HTML.

Comment: I believe that is the title of the message box and can not be changed.

Answer (score 3):

That message can not be modified at all. Your only option is to create your own html/javascript alert window but it won't be truly modal. You can at best give the illusion of a modal window.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom-made alert. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/DOMAlert.aspx