# How to give title to alert box?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

When I run my javascript program,I am getting alert box that has title(page at local host says that).I want to remove that with some good title.Does it there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with standard alert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using alert(), try using a lightbox instead. If you use jQuery, check out jqModal. If you use Prototype, check out ModalBox.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JqueryUI for custom dialogboxes. That way you can specify title, text, buttons, and even style everything to match your website.

Here's the explanation of how to do it: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with javascript alert. Try with custom jquery-ui dialog; [here is the link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change alert box title. You should try custom message box, implemented in pure HTML, like this [one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)