# How to customize the alert title in alert popups in iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, alert

I want to customize the alert title in my alert popups in iphone. Right now it is using the html page name in the title. Like AddDetail.html says: and so on. But, I don't want to display the name of my html pages to the users.

Comment: This is not possible, let me refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title

Comment: You must be adding the html page name as a title to your alert object while initialization. Just add your desired title there instead of the html page name.

Comment: No alert() method takes the name of the html page by which it is called.

Comment: is this a native app? or a cross platform? Be more specific and clear with you question..

Comment: This is a phonegap application and not a native application.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right from the comments, this is a Phonegap / Cordova application.

Then you should check: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

syntax: `navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])`