# Change the title of the alert baox in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the title of the alert box in java Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a dialog box? Try http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to security reasons.

If you wish to have custom titled message boxes, try jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com)

(Similar question: [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title))