# How to get rid of title from a prompt box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code :

```
var answer = prompt('ENTER YOUR TEXT);
```

When javascript executes it puts up the prompt box but gives it a title on top of the box of the html file that this code is part of.

Any way to get rid of that?

Comment: It's not possible, use a [Modal/Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) instead with jQuery's UI components.

Comment: ... or, if you don't want to use jQUery UI, build your own modal dialog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Comment: lots of plugins for doing this...with far better visual appeal than browser default

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. Try something like apprise instead

```
Apprise('Name:', {input:true});
```

http://labs.bigroomstudios.com/libraries/Apprise-v2

**Edit below**

This solves the issue in a neat way!

```
window.prompt = function(text, callback) {

    var options = {
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                text: 'Send',
                action: function(e) {
                    callback(e.input);
                    Apprise('close');
                }
            },
        },
        input: true
    };

    Apprise(text, options);
};

prompt("Say something", function(returnValue) {
    console.log(returnValue);
});
```

Comment: Not familiar with Appraise, but when using that or similar solutions, be warned that they are not blocking, so code that comes after displaying the modal dialog will be executed before user takes action. This may or may not be what you want. Sometimes a callback function can solve this problem, sometimes it can't.

Comment: Not sure how to use the above code.  Where do I put it and where does it take the info the user puts in (i guess what you're calling return value) and makes a variable of it, say call it "answer" as in my original post?

Comment: and you also have Apprise in the code.  Where and how is Apprise defined.  I'm a newbie at this.