# How to change the title of javascript alert box in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In ASP.Net I am using an `ImageButton` on click of which I am showing `JavaScript` `confirm` button like below:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imageButtonDelete" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/delete.png" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("regionId") %>' OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
```

However, in Chrome, the title of the alert box shows -

> the page at localhost:1150 says

I don't want `the page at...` text. How to change that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you can't it's a security/anti-phishing feature,
Refer this link for more information
[change alert title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

However, if you want to display a box to the user then you can construct such box through jquery modal. Here is a nice link which shows how to create it 
[jquery-modal](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

> This should not be specific to ASP.net, but specific to the browser.

You may use some JavaScript library like [jQuery Alert](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/), etc. for generating a JavaScript confirm box which would work in a similar way.