# What are different options for scriptmanager

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am not familiar and expert of the java script. So, please help me with this command:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Success", "alert('Error');"true);
```

What are the different options can be done instead of "success"?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter is just a key to identify the script block.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static void RegisterStartupScript
( Page page,
  Type type,
  string key,
  string script,
  bool addScriptTags
)
```

> key
>
> Type: System.String
>
> A unique identifier for the script block.

Comment: The issue is that the text is "message from the webapp" comes in the header of the message box. My question is how to improve this text and give another text

Comment: Not possible. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title

Comment: @user2103335: Do you need more help? If not, please close this question by marking it as answered.