# "JavaScript application" Alert message

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, fennec

I'm creating an extension for Firefox for Android which adds dinamically some elements to DOM, and some of them needs to display an alert message.

```
var li=window.content.document.createElement('li');
li.onclick = function(){
   alert("lalalalalalallalallalala");
}
```

So I got it, but when the message is displayed, the alert has a "[JavaScript Application]" title. Is there a way to change that title?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title

Comment: You could use modals instead of alerts, like what bootstrap uses.

Comment: don't use alert. Alert locks up the browser until it's acknowledged, preventing the page from running deferred tasks. You're basically blocking everyone else's work; especially on a mobile platform, that's really not a nice thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **[cannot do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert)** using the `alert` method. Its for the security reasons.

As an alternative you can use [showModalDialog](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-showmodaldialog.shtml) for that purpose instead.

> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing
>   the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed.
>   For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a
>   dialog box (or modal window).