# Is it possible to build Cordova App online?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am making making an app using PhoneGap framework.

PhoneGap provides build Service (http://build.phonegap.com) that allows us to build and **package app in cloud**.You do not need to install any **SDK locally** to build app.

Is there any way to build **cordova app Online**

Comment: phonegap and cordova technically are not same. Phonegap uses cordova as the base. Since phonegap uses cordova internally why do you wan build cordova app online? Why not use the phonegap build? Can you be more specific as to why do want to build cordova app online?

Comment: I followed <https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html> document to install and use cordova.Now i am able to build android app locally using command (cordova build android).For ios and other platforms i need lot of stuff locally.Just to avoid that i am trying to find other way to build app .

Comment: just use phonegap build

Comment: @jcesarmobile you mean i should install phonegap not cordova??

Comment: yes, install phonegap instead of cordova and use the phonegap build service

Comment: even though you may use phonegap build for IOS, How would you test your App? To install the App on Iphone, you would still need a license. You cannot manually load an APP on IOS as you can do in Android.

Comment: @frank how to get license for ios?\

Comment: You need to pay the necessary fees. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/)

Answer (score 6):

Did you try Monaca? They have free plans: https://monaca.io

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Intel XDK platform. I've found very useful to develop in brackets+chrome and test and build in intel xdk. They have a very powerful emulator (over ripple afik). Also intel-xdk is becoming more powerful every day and they are actively improving it.

To build a cordova app in intel you don't need to change anything in your code.

Comment: Summer 2017 Intel IDK will no longer support building Cordova Apps on their servers. Alas.