# How could i build android and ios app from ember app with online platform without downloading SDK and XCODE?

Tags: cordova, ember.js, phonegap-build

Is there any way that I upload my ember app so that the online platform generates it as a app for android ios. I have heared about cordova but it insisted me in downloading Xcode or android SDK. I need an online platform to build

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276903/is-it-possible-to-build-cordova-app-online

Answer (score 0):

A creative solution to avoid installing SDKs and such is that instead of using cordova or corber, you could host your app as a full Progressive Web App. A progressive web app has caching capabilities that are similar to a native web app. They can be added into (at least some) app stores, and when people install them, they would see an icon on their phone just the same as a native app.

If you run a search for "Ember PWA" or "Ember Progressive Web App" you will find many resources and tutorials on this. Every year, for example, the EmberConf schedule is recreated as a Progressive Web App, as a demonstration of the power and capability.

If you are still hoping to build a native web app, look into [corber](http://corber.io/) as well, which can provide a nicer pathway for turning apps from many JS frameworks into native web apps, compared to using cordova directly.