# If statement on a span value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make an alert in `jQuery` when a price is higher than 400.

**Look at there:** `<span class="element-price-value">424,97</span>`

If **value is higher than 400**, I need to make an overlay modal popup that continue is not allowed and page need to refeshed.

**Here is what I did but didn't work...**

```
var price = $(".element-price-value");

if(price > 400){
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

Comment: use bootstrap or some custom styling to create modal overlay

Comment: Forget that bootstrap. I need the function first to work.

Comment: try changing this line var price = $(".element-price-value");
 to var price = parseInt($(".element-price-value").val());

Comment: Did you try that condition by removing the comma in the value?

Comment: you are comparing string with int, convert your price to int and then compare `parseInt(price,10)` and get span text using `$(".element-price-value").text()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Comment: @Satya Why use `.val()`? The element is a `span`

Comment: 424,97 or 424.97 is it a float or int?

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani how is that question, about the title of alert boxes, in any way relevant to this question about reading an integer value from a `span`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Number(price.text().replace(',', '.')) > 400){
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

You need to get the contents of `<span>`. Else you're just refering to the object. Then replace "," with "." and finally get the number from it.
You try to compare numbers, not text, nor objects.

You can see how price, price.text() and Number(price.text()); differ

```js
var price = $(".element-price-value");

if(Number(price.text().replace(',', '.')) > 400){
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
} else {
  alert(price);
  alert(price.text());
  alert(Number(price.text()));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="element-price-value">424.97</span>
```

Comment: But this runs when the page loads not when value is higher.

Comment: The first 3 do, but the one in the `if()` condition does not. I know edited it into an `else{}` block. It would only run if the first condition was false. Just so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This code will also work if you will have in span 400,97

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Getting the value in span
  var value = $('.element-price-value').text();
  // or vanilla js that is faster
  // var value = document.querySelector('.element-price-value').innerText;
  
  // Converting to float and changeing comma to .
  value = parseFloat(value.replace(',','.'))
  
  if(value>400) alert('Higher than 400')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="element-price-value">400,97</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Right now, you are getting only `.element-price-value` span, not the value inside. 
Please, use  `var price = $(".element-price-value").text();`
to get the value inside that span, and parse it with `parseInt()` function.

So, the final result must be like: `var price = parseInt($(".element-price-value").text());`

Comment: This logic is flawed. As you `parseInt()` only the value before the `,` is used, hence `400,97` does not trigger the `alert()`, when it should.

Answer (score -2):

If you have only a value inside `span` tag you can accomplish result like this:

```
var price = parseInt($(".element-price-value").text());
if(price > 400){
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

Comment: This logic is flawed. As you `parseInt()` only the value before the `,` is used, hence `400,97` does not trigger the `alert()`, when it should.