# Is there any way to hide confirm box without heading

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there anyway to hide the confirm box title "On embedded page on this page says".

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm

Comment: No. You can't customize the native one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You must create your own custom confirmation modals/popups (or use an existing library like https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) if you want to fine-tune anything other than the message displayed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such method to do that.

You can create your own modal/confirm dialog.

Or you can use angular these packages

[ngx-dialogs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dialogs)

[ngx-simple-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-simple-modal)