# Why my IP Address shows if I use alert() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, alert, ip-address

Here's the screenshot and the code. And how can I change it to something like "This page says" then alert().

[image: Here's the screenshot]

```
  <button id="hover-me"> Move the cursor over here </button>

  document.getElementById("hover-me").onmouseover = function() {
  alert("You hovered me")};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Comment: It's showing the URL of the website, not your IP address. It just so happens that your website is being served from your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't edit that for security reasons.

You could always make a custom modal box, though.